# How to bring back the result from activity function to orchestrator

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to develop a nodejs azure durable function. The activity function is invoking an API and waiting for a response. Once the response is received it should return the token.

Orchestrator function code:

```
    const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = df.orchestrator(function* (context) {
    const outputs = [];

    // Replace "Hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
    const resultToken=yield context.df.callActivity("AirWatchToken", "Tokyo");
    //outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity("AirWatchToken", "Tokyo"));
    console.log("result1:",resultToken);
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity("CacheActivity", context.bindings.name));
    // outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity("AirWatchToken", "London"));

     //return ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
    return outputs;
});
```

AirWatchToken activity function code:

```
const { request } = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');

function getAirwatchToken(context){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        const ClientID="de4f51918dd44b62a5e50319d4c8135f";
        const Client_Secret="49D47EF2CC837718330136D6DDD02407";
    
        
    
        //Example where text is being passed to the API
      var body = querystring.stringify({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        });
    
      var options = { 
            method: 'POST',   
            hostname: "na.uemauth.vmwservices.com",
            path: "/connect/token",
            //data: "grant_type=client_credentials",
            headers: {'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(ClientID + ':' + Client_Secret).toString('base64'),
                       'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                       'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
                       'Accept' : '*/*',
                       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                       'Connection': 'keep-alive'
                    }    
          };
    
      
      callback = function(response){
        var str='';
    
        response.on('data',function(chunk){
            str+=chunk;
        });
    
        response.on('end',function(){
             obj=JSON.parse(str);
             context.res = {
                    body: obj
                }
             console.log("response from Airwatch inside response",str);
             context.done();
             resolve(str);
        });
    }
    let request = https.request(options,callback);
    request.write(body);
    request.end();
      }); 
}


module.exports = async function (context) {

    var result= await getAirwatchToken(context);
    console.log("result",result);

    //context.df=result;

    return result;
    
    
};
```

Though I am getting proper response in the activity function, "console.log("result",result);" is printing required response. But I am getting null in the orchestrator function "console.log("result1:",resultToken);". Where I am going wrong?
Following is the output that I am getting:

```
    {
    "name": "AirWatchOrchestrator",
    "instanceId": "2a1032899a33403ead226b2a59be8ed6",
    "runtimeStatus": "Completed",
    "input": null,
    "customStatus": null,
    "output": [
        "Hello undefined!"
    ],
    "createdTime": "2022-10-26T14:47:46Z",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2022-10-26T14:47:48Z"
}
```

But in the console I am seeing the response token is getting generated.
result1 is getting printed as 1. I am not getting the exact response back in the orchestrator function.
How do I make sure that the activity function stops till the response token is generated and then the activity function returns the response?

Answer (score 0):

I am using below basic NodeJS azure durable function. I can be able to get the activity function result in orchestrator.

Orchestrator function

```js
import  *  as  df  from  "durable-functions"

const  orchestrator = df.orchestrator(function* (context) {

const  outputs = [];

// Calling Activity function
    outputs.push(yield  context.df.callActivity("<function Name>", "<input>"));
    outputs.push(yield  context.df.callActivity("<function Name>", "<input>"));
    outputs.push(yield  context.df.callActivity("<function Name>", "<input>"));
return  outputs;

});

export  default  orchestrator;
```

Activity function

```js
import { AzureFunction, Context } from  "@azure/functions"

// Function to get the value
function getval(context): Promise<string> {
    return `Activity function result ${context.bindings.name}!`;
}

// calling getval function in activity function
const  activityFunction: AzureFunction = async  function (context: Context){
    var result = await getval(context);
    return result;
};

export  default  activityFunction;
```

I have noticed that in your orchestrator function you are trying to push the Json value from activity function to the orchestration function. You can handle the resposne according to it. Like function **`getval(context): Promise<string>`**.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to exactly pass json string from activity to orchestrator? I tried various things, not able to succeed.